# How to set js variable in style tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have written this code in the js file. But need to use `user_id` js variable inside style tag for content. How to do so?

```js
$('head').append('<style>.video-js:before{content: "user_id";}</style>');
```

Comment: just use concatenation like this: `$('head').append('<style>.video-js:before{content: "' + user_id + '";}</style>');`

Comment: Or use Template Literals (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as this: $('head').append(\`<style>.video-js:before{content: "${user_id}";}</style>\`);

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is resolved this way. May be helpful for someone.

```
var content = '<style>.video-js:before{content: "'+user_id+'";}</style>';
$('head').append(content);
```